# ExpanderView is expanded after page navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I'm using a port of the `WPF` `ExpanderView` ([ExpanderRT](https://expanderview.codeplex.com/)) in my `UWP` app to show expandable headers with items. This works fine when the app is launched for the first time and `MainPage` is initialized. However if I navigate to a new page and then go back to `MainPage` the `ExpanderView` looks like expanded, but not it's not showing the items. It should look the same as it was when `MainPage` was first initialized. I captured a `GIF` to show the behaviour.

This is the `XAML` of the `UserControl` on the `MainPage`;

```
<ListView x:Name="CategoriesListView" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <ListViewItemPresenter ContentMargin="0" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Category">
        <expander:ExpanderControl
            x:Name="expander_Main"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind childItems}"
            Expanded="Expanded" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

This is the `EventHandler` which I use for navigation;

```
    private void OnSettingsButtonChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ShellSplitView.IsPaneOpen = false;
        ViewModel.NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
    }
```

If anyone of you knows why the `ExpanderView` has such a weird behavior, please give me a hint - I can provide more of my code if you need.

[image: Capture]

**[UPDATE]**

I noticed that this behavior only occurs, when I run the app on a mobile device (Smartphone or Mobile Windows 10 Emulator). If I execute the app on the local machine the `ExpanderView` works fine. When I use the back button for navigating back to `MainPage` it works as expected - I don't have a clue how to fix this, it's really weird.

[image: Capture on Desktop]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After debugging the whole code of the `ExpanderRT` control I was able to solve the problem! It's caused by a bug of the original Expander control which was ported over to `WinRT`

I found out, that the height of `_itemsCanvas` in the class `ExpanderControl.cs` is set via this method:

```
private void OnPresenterSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (null != _itemsCanvas && null != _presenter && IsExpanded)
    {
        _itemsCanvas.Height = _presenter.DesiredSize.Height;
    }
}
```

This causes that the size of the item container is only applied when the `ExpanderView` is currently expanded. I simply added the following condition to set the height of the item container to 0 when the `ExpanderView` is currently not expanded.

```
else if (null != _itemsCanvas && null != _presenter && !IsExpanded)
{
   _itemsCanvas.Height = 0;
}
```

I added various improvements to the control to take advantage of new UWP capabilities, so if anyone is interested in a UWP compatible version feel free to contact me.

***UPDATE***

I created a [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/nor0x/UWP_Expander) for the updated ExpanderControl for UWP