# Create a ListBox with items that expand when selected (Accordion)

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox, uwp

There's solutions to this problem for older XAML based UI frameworks (WPF/SL) but they're not easily adaptable to the Universal Windows Platform.

I'm trying to create a list of items that show only limited details in default state and expands, when it's selected, to quickly edit some data.
I have not found a way to create a that expanding behavior, though it is similar to what the Windows 10 Mail app does, with conversations. When a message of a conversation is selected, the other messages of that conversation kind of drop down or slide down.

Below is an example of a list where I'd like to display only the name at first.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind Persons}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="src:Person">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="12, 15, 12, 0" FontSize="18.667" />
                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="12, 12, 12, 0" FontSize="18.667" Text="{x:Bind Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <TextBlock Text="Date of birth" Margin="12, 15, 12, 0" />
                <DatePicker Margin="12, 5, 12, 0" Date="{x:Bind Path=DateOfBirth, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <TextBlock Text="Domicile" Margin="12, 15, 12, 0" />
                <TextBox Margin="12, 5, 12, 0" Text="{x:Bind Path=Domicile, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In WPF, such behavior could be achieved with triggers `Style.Triggers` but they're not available anymore.

Original Source Code on [GitHub](https://github.com/elessar-ch/uwp-list-box-test/blob/master/ListBoxTest/MainPage.xaml)

Comment: You still have triggers available to you in UWP, and there's several ways you could do this in pure XAML, one quick and simple way I could think of doing this. Make an ItemTemplate with a styled ToggleButton and a Panel below it collpased. Then Bind the Visibility of the panel to the IsChecked state of the ToggleButton and add a Bool to Visibility converter, voila, done.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you want to do. You want to use the ListViewItem.IsSelected property that is natively set by the ListView. Then, you want to react to that value change and set a visual state that reveals or hides your details.

Like this:

```
class MyModel
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

class MyList : Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListView
{
    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        var model = item as MyModel;
        var listViewItem = element as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewItem;

        var binding = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.Binding
        {
            Source = model,
            Mode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.BindingMode.TwoWay,
            Path = new PropertyPath(nameof(model.IsSelected)),
        };
        listViewItem.SetBinding(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewItem.IsSelectedProperty, binding);
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
    }
}
```

Funny enough but this code is somewhat based on the code used for variable sized wrap grids. You can read the original article here.

> http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/08/windows-8-beauty-tip-using.html

If you want to learn more about the Visual States, you might read over the blog article I wrote on the same subject.

> http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/11/windows-81-how-to-use-visual-states-in.html

Something like this:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
            <Core:GoToStateAction StateName="BigVisualState"/>
        </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
        <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="False">
            <Core:GoToStateAction StateName="LittleVisualState"/>
        </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="BigVisualState"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="LittleVisualState"/>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

</Grid>
```

If you would like to learn more about XAML behaviors in Windows apps, you can read the article I wrote on the subject.

> http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/10/everything-i-know-about-behaviors-in.html

I also recorded a course you might like.

> https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/designing-your-xaml-ui-with-blend-jump-start-8260?l=p2dPykKy_5104984382

I hope this helps.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I created an expandable `ListView` control for UWP - you can find it [here](https://github.com/nor0x/UWP_Expander) in the GitHub repo. It's actually a ported version of the `WPF Expander` which I adapted to work with the universal windows platform.

You can find my question and answer here on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32607039/expanderview-is-expanded-after-page-navigation).

Answer (score 0):

Like Chris Said, we can add a property in ViewModel to control the expanding behavior, but this need to change the ViewModel. If you don't want to do this, here is another approach:

Firstly, we need two `DataTemplate`, one for displaying brief information and the other for displaying details. For example:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <!--  brief information template  -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate" x:DataType="src:Person">
        <StackPanel Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <TextBlock Margin="12, 15, 12, 0"
                       FontSize="18.667"
                       Text="{x:Bind Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <TextBox Margin="12, 12, 12, 0"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                     FontSize="18.667"
                     Text="{x:Bind Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <!--  details expand template  -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SelectedTemplate" x:DataType="src:Person">
        <StackPanel Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <TextBlock Margin="12, 15, 12, 0"
                       FontSize="18.667"
                       Text="{x:Bind Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <TextBox Margin="12, 12, 12, 0"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                     FontSize="18.667"
                     Text="{x:Bind Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Margin="12, 15, 12, 0" Text="Date of birth" />
                <DatePicker Margin="12, 5, 12, 0" Date="{x:Bind Path=DateOfBirth, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <TextBlock Margin="12, 15, 12, 0" Text="Domicile" />
                <TextBox Margin="12, 5, 12, 0" Text="{x:Bind Path=Domicile, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

Then in `ListBox` set the default `ItemTemplate` to brief information template.

```
<ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"
         ItemsSource="{x:Bind Persons}"
         SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Finally, add a event handler to `SelectionChanged` event and in this handler change `ContentTemplate` for the selected and unselected item.

```
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var listBox = sender as ListBox;
    //get unselected item
    var unselectedPerson = e.RemovedItems.FirstOrDefault() as Person;
    if (unselectedPerson != null)
    {
        //get unselected item container
        var unselectedItem = listBox.ContainerFromItem(unselectedPerson) as ListBoxItem;
        //set ContentTemplate
        unselectedItem.ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["ItemTemplate"];
    }
    //get selected item container
    var selectedItem = listBox.ContainerFromItem(listBox.SelectedItem) as ListBoxItem;
    selectedItem.ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["SelectedTemplate"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution using MVVM:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Title" />
                <TextBlock Text="Details" Visibility="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

```
public class ViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private Item _selectedItem;


    public Item[] Items { get; }

    public Item SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedItem != null) _selectedItem.IsSelected = false;
            if (value != null) value.IsSelected = true;
            SetProperty(ref _selectedItem, value);
        }
    }
}

public class Item : BindableBase
{
    private bool _isSelected;

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _isSelected, value); }
    }
}
```

Another solution would be to edit ListBoxItem.ControlTemplate instead of ListBox.ItemTemplate, where you can databind visibility to ListBoxItem.IsSelected property, take advantage of visual states.